# Inductor identification

Tags: inductor, automotive

Please help; I am not able to identify this inductor from its bandings; I've never had to replace one before. This is from the Toyota SRS Airbag Sensor Array in a 1996 Toyota Granvia. The Sensor has failed, the diagnostics confirm this, I cannot get the part any longer, and so I need to fix it or write the whole machine off for want of a little electronics. It has got a rupture along the top side of it, and what looks to be smoke scorching on the PCB traces beside it.

And yes, I am aware of the need for extreme caution in dealing with the airbag system[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a wider photo of the PCB would help.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Edited to supply one, thanks.

Comment: If you can't source the part from an electronics route, consider junkyards. They have networks where they can search for a 1996 Toyota Granvia SRS and can even pull a part for you and mail it to you (for a fee). Just requisition the whole sensor array.

Comment: By the way, if a junked Granvia is hard to find in your area, there's an excellent chance the same inductor (and module) was used on other contemporary Toyota models. It would take more digging to figure this out and find one, but it's possible, when the alternative is writing off the vehicle.

Comment: Something else caused the inductor to fail, so you’d need to identify the cause before replacing the inductor.

Comment: Consider the safety and legal aspects. What happens if the airbag goes off in your face when you're in the fast lane? And, having "repaired" the airbag sensor yourself, you certainly can't in all good conscience sell the car afterwards. I'd strongly lean towards a board replacement as others have suggested.